# Подскажите, как выйти с цикла?

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Использую команду `call m`, чтобы вернуться на метку m, так как идентичный цикл писать неразумно как-то. И вопрос заключается в следующем: как выйти с подобного цикла (при этом команда `call` должна использоваться обязательно) и если делать проверку-сравнение после цикла командой `cmp` (перед командой `call m`), возможно не получится второй раз обратиться к циклу...

```
code    segment                 
assume      cs:code, ds:code

start: 
add bh,0h       ; перевірка числа на парність
mov si,1h
mov cx,4h       
mov al,10h 
m:
mov ds:[si],al
inc si
inc al 
loop m
mov si,6h
mov cx,4h   
mov al,10h
call m
code    ends
end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call - это вызов функции, которая должна завершиться командой ret.
А просто вернуться на адрес m - есть операнд jmp.
Сейчас у тебя в коде полный бардак, ты вызываешь call внутри самого себя, не завершив его, в итоге ты получишь переполнение стека и синий экран (ну, раньше так было, сейчас система поумнее стала).
В итоге, твой код должен быть примерно таким

```
mov si,1h
mov cx,4h       
mov al,10h 
call m
code    ends
end start
m:
mov ds:[si],al
inc si
inc al 
loop m
mov si,6h
mov cx,4h   
mov al,10h
ret
```

Comment: бардак в коде, так как я вырезал только кусочек из своего основного кода:) но есть еще вопрос - как в Вашем коде заново инициализировать метку m, если Вы используете `code ends` почти в начале самого кода? (отладчик показывает о не определении метки)